# Effects of the negative bit

Tags: bit, negative-number

How does the negative bit work?

Why does the negative bit allow negative numbers to have an absolute value 1 greater than positive ones (two's compliment)?

Why isn't this bit read in as 2^x, where c is the number of bits?

I just don't understand, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that is stored in computers is just a bunch of bits.  It is the conventions established by humans that attributes meaning to those bits.  For example, 01000001 may represent an `A` according to the ASCII standard.

As another example, 10100100 may be interpreted as `¤` (the generic currency sign) in ISO-8859-1 or as `€` (the Euro sign) in ISO-8859-15.

Analogously, the first bit of a number may be interpreted as a negative-sign bit if those bits are supposed to store a signed number in two's complement form.  We could choose to treat 10100100 as either an unsigned byte (one hundred sixty-four) or as a signed byte (negative ninety-two).

Specifically, interpreting 10100100 as an unsigned number is straightforward:

> 1 * 2^7 + 0 * 2^6 + 1 * 2^5 + 0 * 2^4 + 0 * 2^3 + 1 * 2^2 + 0 * 2^1 + 0 * 2^0

To interpret 10100100 as a signed number in two's complement form, note that by convention, the first bit indicates that the number is negative, so the following process kicks in:

> - Invert the bits, to 01011011.
> - 0 * 2^7 + 1 * 2^6 + 0 * 2^5 + 1 * 2^4 + 1 * 2^3 + 0 * 2^2 + 1 * 2^1 + 1 * 2^0 = 91
> - Negate and subtract one: -91 - 1 = -92.

Comment: So if a variable is `signed` the first bit signifies negative or positive. If it is unsigned, it is just `2^x` based on how many bits?

Comment: Yes, that is the convention.

Answer (score 0):

[From wikipedia :](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations)

With two complement, you do not have two representations of 0 :

Say, for example, you have a signed integer coded on 3 bits :

- 000 => 0
- 001 => 1
- 010 => 2
- 011 => 3
- 100 => -4
- 101 => -3
- 110 => -2
- 111 => -1

With one complement, 000 and 111 would both represent 0, and your bounds would be -3:3

- 000 => 0
- 001 => 1
- 010 => 2
- 011 => 3
- 100 => -3
- 101 => -2
- 110 => -1
- 111 => -0 (wich is actually 0)

Comment: How to the last two work?

How is `1000` = 8? Shouldn't it be `0100`?
Same with the `1111` = -1. That ones just completely confusing.

Comment: I will update this example with 3 bits so you understand better. When you reach your positive boundary, you start from your negative boundary.